# how to calculate the file size in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

In my asp mvc 3 application, I have an action which allows the user to download a given file.

Here is the code :

```
public FilePathResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string uploadsDocumentPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uploadsDocumentPath"].ToString();
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext); // henter info fra windows registry
            if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            {
                mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
            }

            return File(uploadsDocumentPath + fileName, mimeType, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to allow only files with size less than 150MB to be downloaded. But I can't find how to calculate this type of file's size.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(uploadsDocumentPath + fileName);
if(file.Length > 157286400)
{
      // Return error here.
}
```

Comment: 150000000 is not 150MB. 157286400 is 150MB = 1024x1024x150

Comment: @JeffYates I made an estimate ;)